# Want search with button on click instead of input on keyup. PHP and MYSQL

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I have form:**

```
    <form class="form-inline" style="width: 100%;">
    <input name="vyhledat_text" id="vyhledat_text" type="search" style="width: 69%;margin-right:1%;border-radius: 0;" class="form-control" placeholder="Vyhledat ...">
    <button style="width: 30%;border-radius: 0;" class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Vyhledat</button>
    </form>
```

**and script:**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

         load_data();

         function load_data(query)
         {
          $.ajax({
           url:"fetch.php",
           method:"POST",
           data:{query:query},
           success:function(data)
           {
            $('#výsledek').html(data);
           }
          });
         }
         $('#vyhledat_text').keyup(function(){
          var search = $(this).val();
          if(search != '')
          {
           load_data(search);
          }
          else
          {
           load_data();
          }
         });
        });
        </script>`
```

**and the result:**

```
<div id="výsledek"></div>
```

And I want to know how to make search on button NOT on keyup  when I change it to *click.(function()* it search only on clicking on the input NOT on the button. Can you help me please? I don't know where I did the mistake/problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button onclick handler example, here you do the same as on `keyup` handler, but difference is that you take value from `$('#vyhledat_text').val();` instead of `$(this).val();`

Also you need to prevent default `submit` event. I did it with `e.preventDefault()`;

```
  $('.btn.btn-outline-primary').click(function(e){

      e.preventDefault();

      var search = $('#vyhledat_text').val();
      if(search != '')
      {
       load_data(search);
      }
      else
      {
       load_data();
      }

  })
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: It will show "/index.php?vyhledat_text=" and do nothink Do you want to see fetch.php code?

Comment: I updated my answer, with preventing default `submit` event

Comment: Love you! +rep Thank you very much.